# temperature calculator

Tags: calculator, temperature

Hi i am suppose to make a Temperature calculator that will accept either Celsius or perimeter and convert that temperature to the other scale. If a Celsius temperature is entered it will be converted to Fahrenheit and vice versa.

Instructions:

> For this you will have to design and code a method to convert one temperature scale to another and return the result.  This single method should take two arguments, one for the temperature value to convert and a second indicating which temperature scale to convert to.
>
> Your method should be coded so that it could be accessed by another class or application.  Also, make sure there is only one return statement in your method.

So far i have created this code but it showing me 2 small errors and i don't know how to fix them.

**error 1. Constant value '67' cannot be converted to a 'char'

error 2. Constant value '70' cannot be converted to a 'char'**

namespace Lab7
{
    public partial class frmTemperatureConverter : Form
    {
        public frmTemperatureConverter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void txtValueToConver_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char chr;
        string str1;
        string str2;
        object[] objArray;
        if (this.txtConvert.Text != "")
        {
            double num1 = double.Parse(this.txtConvert.Text);
            if (this.radCelsius.Checked)
            {
                chr = 67;
                str1 = "farenheit";
                str2 = "celsius";
            }
            else
            {
                chr = 70;
                str1 = "celsius";
                str2 = "farenheit";
            }
            double num2 = Math.Round(this.ConvertTemperature(num1, chr), 2);
            this.lblResult.Text = string.Concat(new object[] { num1, " ", str1, " converts to ", num2, " ", str2 });
        }
        else
        {
            this.lblResult.Text = "Please enter a numeric temperature to convert.";
            this.txtConvert.Focus();
        }
    }

    public double ConvertTemperature(double inTemp, char toScale)
    {
        double num;
        if (toScale == 70)
        {
            num = inTemp * 1.80 + 32.00;
        }
        else
        {
            if (toScale == 67)
            {
                num = (inTemp - 32.00) / 1.80;
            }
            else
            {
                num = inTemp;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtConvert.Text = "";
        this.lblResult.Text = "";
        this.txtConvert.Focus();
        this.radCelsius.Checked = true;
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 67 and 70 are not characters -- they are integers.

The simplest thing would to make the variable "chr" an integer.  Then you should probably change its name too -- perhaps to "toScale" -- the same as the parameter name.

Or you could leave the variable "chr" as a char, and use the values 'C' instead of 67 and 'F' instead of 70. This method makes it easier to understand the program, too.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem are those lines:

```
char chr;  
chr = 67;  
chr = 70;
```

chr ist of type char, so you need to cast this number to char:

```
chr = (char)67;
```

Comment: thanks thats solved the problem but i have an small error, it says "the variable  'objArray' is declared but never used. Should i just delete the line "object[] objArray;" ?

Comment: sure, if you dont need the array